# split utf-8 string into bytes in python

Tags: python, utf-8

I am trying to split an UTF-8 string into bytes in python 3. The problem is, when I use bytearray, byte, encode etc functions I always get an array with size of element 14 bytes, not 1 byte as I expected. I need to split any text file into sequence of bytes and send them byte after byte using sockets. I tried something like this:

```
infile = open (file, "r")
str = infile.read()
byte_str = bytes(str, 'UTF-8')
print("size of byte_str",sys.getsizeof(byte_str[0]))
```

Print gives me 14, but I need 1... Any suggestion?

Comment: You could open the file with `rb` to get a bytes object from read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

```
sys.getsizeof(object[, default])
```

> Return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of
>   object. All built-in objects will return correct results, but this
>   does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is
>   implementation specific.
>
> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is
>   accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.
>
> If given, default will be returned if the object does not provide
>   means to retrieve the size. Otherwise a TypeError will be raised.
>
> getsizeof() calls the object’s `__sizeof__` method and **adds an
>   additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the
>   garbage collector**.
>
> See recursive sizeof recipe for an example of using getsizeof()
>   recursively to find the size of containers and all their contents.